# Ruby Process.kill can't kill exec() for certain shell commands

Tags: ruby

I use `fork` and `exec` to run an async shell command for running Xcode tests. I want to stop running tests when I kill the process, but it acts differently when I use different commands:

```rb
def processAlive?(pid)
  Process.getpgid( pid ) && true rescue false
end

pid = fork {
  test_command = "xcodebuild test-without-building -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyProject"
  full_command = "#{test_command} 2>/dev/null"

  # choose one of the following to run tests
  exec(test_command)  # This would be interrupted when killed
  exec(full_command)  # This would NOT be interrupted when killed
}

puts "pid: #{pid}; alive? #{processAlive?(pid)}"
sleep 2
Process.kill('KILL', pid)
sleep 0
puts "pid: #{pid}; alive? #{processAlive?(pid)}"
```

When I run just `xcodebuild` command (`exec(test_command)`), it will be stopped to print test results when killing the process.

After adding `2>/dev/null` to the shell command, the test runner couldn't be stopped and still keep printing results when killing the process.

I wonder why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Kernel#exec` is smart enough *not* to spawn a system shell when it's not necessary.

Using your script (with Xcode command replaced with `sleep 999`) and `pstree`, the following process hierarchy is observed right after the script starts:

```sh
# Without redirection
ibug@iBug-Server:~ $ pstree
init─┬─<irrelevant>
     ├─init───tmux: client
     ├─tmux: server─┬─bash───ruby───sleep
     │              └─bash───pstree
     └─{init}

# With redirection
ibug@iBug-Server:~ $ pstree
init─┬─<irrelevant>
     ├─init───tmux: client
     ├─sleep
     ├─tmux: server─┬─bash───ruby───sh───sleep
     │              └─bash───pstree
     └─{init}
```

After the `Process.kill` line, the output of `pstree` turns into

```sh
# Without redirection
ibug@iBug-Server:~ $ pstree
init─┬─<irrelevant>
     ├─init───tmux: client
     ├─tmux: server─┬─bash
     │              └─bash───pstree
     └─{init}

# With redirection
ibug@iBug-Server:~ $ pstree
init─┬─<irrelevant>
     ├─init───tmux: client
     ├─sleep                 # <=== Note here
     ├─tmux: server─┬─bash
     │              └─bash───pstree
     └─{init}
```

This is because you KILL-ed the parent process (`sh`) of the Ruby `exec(command)` in the second case, which got left orphaned and attached to PID 1 instead, so it continued running and generating outputs.

To "get rid of" the intermediate shell, let it `exec` to the target process should suffice.

```rb
test_command = "exec #{test_command}"
```

Now in both cases, with and without redirection, the actual job process is killed properly.

Comment: Thanks, it works with `2>/dev/null` like this: `"exec #{test_command} 2>/dev/null"`, 

but it fails again when I pipe the results to `xcpretty`: `"exec #{test_command} 2>/dev/null | xcpretty"`. How could I fix this?

Comment: @XareeLee In that case you'd better examing `Process.spawn` rather than fork-then-exec - it's completely unnecessary to do this in Ruby.

Comment: Is there any way to use `Process.spawn` with a ruby block? I read the ruby docs only showing that it takes a shell command to run.

Comment: @XareeLee You probably don't need to spawn a Ruby block. Just work out the command you'd put in `exec` and use `Process.spawn` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but how to sync the process code? I've tried `pid = Process.spawn(full_command)`, but it stops at `Process.wait(pid)` after finishing the command. :(

Comment: @XareeLee Can't reproduce. According to [rubydoc.info](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Process.spawn), `Process.wait pid` *should* continue after the child process completes.